# Moving sheet from one WB to another New WB

Tags: excel, vba

I have made the following code for moving sheet from one WB to another New WB.

However I am experiencing errors.

```
Sub MoveSheets01()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim newWB As Workbook
   Dim oldwb As Workbook

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set oldwb = ActiveWorkbook
   Set newWB = Application.Workbooks.Add

   oldwb.Activate

   For Each ws In oldwb.Sheets
      If ws.Name <> "Input" And ws.Name <> "Output" Then
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         ws.Copy after:=newWB.Sheets(newWB.Sheets.Count)
         ws.Delete
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      End If
   Next ws

   oldwb.Save
   newWB.Activate
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   newWB.SaveAs Filename:=oldwb.Path & "\AAA " & Format(Now(), "DD.MMM.YYYY hh.mm AMPM") & ".xlsx", CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

It generates a new WB.

But the moment I save either, the file crashes.

Comment: the file is at https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ttKsEY5B01Xyg21ADGW7vTLvvIgUaSZA

Answer (score 0):

Try this. See comments, especially regarding the filename. Most likely you have too long filename. If error occurs - post a comment with error text.

```
Sub MoveSheets010()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newWB As Workbook
Dim oldwb As Workbook
Dim link As Variant

' switch this off for the whole sub
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set oldwb = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In oldwb.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Input" And ws.Name <> "List" _
        And ws.Name <> "Temp" And ws.Name <> "Index Data" _
        And ws.Name <> "Ratio's" And ws.Name <> "Total Returns Index" _
        And ws.Name <> "India VIX" And ws.Name <> "Output" Then
    '   check whether newWB is assigned
        If Not newWB Is Nothing Then
            ' if assigned - just add sheet there
            ws.Move before:=newWB.Sheets(1)
        Else
            ' if not assign - create new workbook by moving the sheet
            ' this creates new workbook with only one sheet
            ' so there will be no "Sheet1", "Sheet2", etc
            ws.Move
            ' assign newWB
            Set newWB = ActiveWorkbook
        End If
    End If
Next

Set ws = Nothing

' save new wb first to avoid message about links/references
newWB.SaveAs Filename:=oldwb.Path & "\AAA " & Format(Now(), "DD.MMM.YYYY hh.mm AMPM") & ".xlsx", CreateBackup:=False

' remove references from source wb and save it
With oldwb
If Not IsEmpty(.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)) Then
    For Each link In .LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
        .BreakLink link, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next link
End If
    .Save
End With

' switch this on back
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Still both the newWB & oldWB has some interlinking.

the file is shared at

https://drive.google.com/file/d/181ox38CDiuAGjIXxqnD9b8fvPdAMN49_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: but still linking both WB at my end.

Comment: Still Not working.

Output File shared below

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kzrje7s7GJ1YW_-d_wu770glsLGdljog/view?usp=sharing

Comment: To generate sheet, Run Indices()
.
I understand the output files has some Named Range, which is linking , when file is moved.
Now I am not able to break that link

Comment: Now it is working fine
I have removed the named ranges.
It works find now.
Thanks @Vitaliy Prushak